# How to change the color of an array index in android?

Tags: android, arrays

I just want change the color of a particular array index , i have the following array -:

```
String [] all={"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"};

 GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);

 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
              android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, all);         

      gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

      new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.item_layout);

      gridView.setChoiceMode(1);

      gridView.setItemChecked(6, true);
```

XML Code -: **item_layout.xml**

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

      <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:textColor="#f00"

     />
```

I have tried to change the color of index 6 to red but it's printing all in black color. Please help me out , how can i change the color of index 6 to red and all other to black.

I want to print the resultant array through ArrayAdapter only.

Thank in Advance !!!

Comment: Why did you ask same question ?

Comment: Umm, no i got the answer code from my previous question and i was trying to execute and every element got red , so i want to clarify more... to get the proper answer.

Comment: Don't create a new question. Instead, comment on the answer to ask/confirm/give feedback. Edit: by the way, I see that you didn't really follow the answer 100%. `android:textColor="#f00"` makes all text red.

Comment: oK sorry , i will do that in future .. so please help me out .. by solve my problem ... i am not able to find any clue to change the particular index to red color ....

Comment: @Andrew T Yes  , i  was trying but when i was following actual answer nothing got change , so i changed to #foo , and yes everything going red... please suggest me more specific answer....

Answer (score 0):

1. Change your data source to also include the items' colors. This might be done via a custom data item class.
2. Create your own subclass of `ArrayAdapter`. In `getView()` of this adapter, inflate your xml, fill it with your data and set the background color according to your data source.#

A tutorial like [this](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429) will help you get started.